# Statements on GDPR with respect to FOSS

Tags: law, website

The [General Data Protection Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) that is about to come into effect in the EU appears to impose requirements to (among others) [anyone who runs a website of public interest](https://gdpr-info.eu/recitals/no-18/). As some of these requirements are difficult to fulfil for projects developed during people's spare time without any revenue (e.g. getting legal counsel for a legally watertight privacy policy text, getting webspace and an e-mail inbox whose providers agree to sign [processing agreements](http://www.privacy-regulation.eu/en/article-28-processor-GDPR.htm)<sup>1</sup>, etc.), this might prevent EU-based FOSS projects from having a website aside from the default project profile pages on Github and the like<sup>2</sup>.

Have there been any statements by the people or institutions behind the GDPR on what the expected effect on open source software projects will be (e.g. the described issues are an intended/unintended side effect, the issues won't occur because ..., they consider the issues irrelevant, ...)?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Also see: [*Contract necessary for the most basic processing under GPDR?*](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/25546/contract-necessary-for-the-most-basic-processing-under-gpdr) on [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)

<sup>2</sup>: Note that I'm not referring to the few high-profile projects out there that are backed by foundations and such.

Answer (score 4):

The GDPR applies when processing personal data. The solution for open source projects: Don't process personal data. A static website without any analytics does not perform meaningful processing of personal data.

If you as a project maintainer are still concerned about this, write a short privacy policy that personal data such as IP addresses are processed for the sole purpose of displaying the site, and sign a data processing agreement with your hoster. Currently, I can't find any indication that GitHub or GitLab offer a DPA, but many EU-based hosters do.

If you do process any data, then of course the GDPR applies even for hobby projects. The point of the law is to protect personal data, not to punish businesses. And aside from this initial panic, compliance does not take much effort when not processing personal data.

From the GDPR perspective, accepting pull requests into a git repo is much more problematic, since the blockchain-nature of git makes it impossible to delete or correct personal information (such as author name and email addresses) afterwards. However, this is not necessarily in violation if you obtain prior informed consent from contributors.

Comment: Very insightful, thank you. Interestingly, the first paragraph of the answers appears to contradict everything I have read about GDPR in German. The consensus among German articles on the topic seems to be that the requirement to provide a GDPR-conformant privacy policy applies to virtually all websites, and as virtually all web hosters do at least temporarily log IP addresses, there is invariably some relevant processing of personal data. Furthermore, as soon as someone sends an e-mail related to your website to the address stated there, that's more personal data whose GDPR-conformant ...

Comment: ... handling you have to ensure and declare in the privacy policy. Do you have any references or analyses that back up this opposing view your answer presents (in particular by the parties involved in defining GDPR, to also match with my original question)? In any case, the takeaway from your second paragraph seems to be that EU-based open source project maintainers should use the U.S.-based open source sites only for the integrated tools such as VCS and bug trackers, and move their self-designed websites to an EU-based hoster that provides a DPA.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My answer is largely based on original research. I don't think it presents an opposing view. No, I have not looked for statements. Note that the data protection authorities will have their hands full dealing with actual violations. I don't forsee a regulatory clampdown on benign open source projects that just don't have their papers in order. Consider also that the German BDSG is generally equivalent or stricter than the GDPR, yet no such enforcement has happened against German FLOSS projects.

Comment: The GDPR could be reduced to absurdity that every router on the internet would have to provide you a privacy policy because they temporarily process your IP address & packet contents. However, that seems unworkable given the technically reality. So yes, under a strict interpretation _every_ website that's subject to the GDPR must have a privacy policy, even if only to inform the user that no information whatsoever is logged but only processed temporarily. This would also require a DPA with the hoster.

Comment: I wouldn't consider my personal email address to be subject to the GDPR (purely personal use, see Art. 2(2)(c)), even if I publish it through git commits to some project.

Comment: It could be argued that with VCS hosting & issue tracking, the repo owner and not the platform is the data controller. Then, the hosting platform would be a data processor, with whom the controller must sign a DPA under Art 28(3) – regardless of whether the processor is in the US or EU. In the case of GitHub, they are not currently offering any DPA but are [claiming](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/GDPR-and-GitHub/m-p/6126/highlight/true#M2002) to work towards compliance (they really dropped the ball on this, since their 30 day window for policy changes has expired).

Comment: Actually, I missed their update: https://blog.github.com/2018-04-19-updates-to-our-privacy-statement-and-terms-of-service/ – but it doesn't seem clear how they are going to support DPAs.

Comment: Ultimately, I'm not concerned about data protection authorities. I'm rather wary of the next series of costly [cease-and-desist letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abmahnung) from people who want to make a quick buck by finding possible formal mistakes on hobbyist websites, and who might even get some occasional support from courts if there are no clear indications the regulations were not intended to be interpreted that way. Concerning the e-mail address, I wonder if it can be considered "purely personal" if it's the contact address for a website that is, arguably, not "purely ...

Comment: ... personal". The interpretation that the repo owner might be the data controller, even though they have no influence on what the website around the repo appears like, is an interesting, albeit (hopefully) unlikely one. I'll keep track of news on the Github blog, in any case. I'll upvote this answer for now, but I won't accept it as "the" answer for the time being, in case another answer might indeed turn up some "semi-official" statements later on.

Comment: You just wrote "GDPR does not apply to static websites without analytics" , what about IP logs of the website?

Comment: @compenthusiast This answer was written 2.5 years ago and my understanding of GDPR has since deepened. I am now of the opinion that any website performs processing of personal data precisely because IP addresses and other traffic data (as defined by ePrivacy) are likely to be personal data (as defined by GDPR).

Comment: Did you feel I was blaming you or something.Not at all Actually I am searching GDPr and CCPA every where because it seems impossible to understand how small developers will comply with GDPR. I cannot even host a GitHub Pages site .What is this!

Comment: @amon: So, is there any new conclusion to this answer when we combine the statements "And aside from this initial panic, compliance does not take much effort when not processing personal data." and "I am now of the opinion that any website performs processing of personal data"?